# kafka stream statestore restoration problem

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka-streams, aggregation, rocksdb, kubernetes-statefulset

we are using KafkaStream for data aggregation. we have about 1000 K records per day to aggregate and our source and stateStore-changelog topic have 6 partitions. also size of stateStore is about 50 G.

to avoid long restoration time after restarting services we are using statefulset pods with 2 replicas.

but we are facing 2 issues:

1. during restoration phase, it goes to PENDING_SHUTDOWN state and then kafka stream thread shutdowns completely. after restarting pod it starts restoration again, but this state happens another time and restoration fails. final state is State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD and after that service does nothing.

here is full log:

```
10:49:20.001 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
10:49:20.001 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
10:49:20.003 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.StandbyTask | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] standby-task [0_5] Suspended running
10:49:20.008 | INFO | o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): aggregator-Stats-changelog-2
10:49:50.113 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.StandbyTask | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] standby-task [0_5] Closed dirty
10:49:50.113 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] task [0_2] Suspended RESTORING
10:49:50.115 | INFO | o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
10:50:13.051 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] task [0_2] Closing record collector dirty
10:50:13.052 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] task [0_2] Closed dirty
10:50:13.055 | INFO | o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer | [Producer clientId=aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
10:50:13.061 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics scheduler closed
10:50:13.062 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
10:50:13.062 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics reporters closed
10:50:13.063 | INFO | o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser | App info kafka.producer for aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1-producer unregistered
10:50:13.064 | INFO | o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
10:50:13.064 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics scheduler closed
10:50:13.064 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
10:50:13.064 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics reporters closed
10:50:13.067 | INFO | o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser | App info kafka.consumer for aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1-consumer unregistered
10:50:13.067 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics scheduler closed
10:50:13.067 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
10:50:13.067 | INFO | o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics reporters closed
10:50:13.070 | INFO | o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser | App info kafka.consumer for aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer unregistered
10:50:13.071 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
10:50:13.071 | INFO | o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [aggregator-7034b814-b6f5-4784-8ea5-01d2c402a4b5-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
```

2. during restoration phase i check stateStore size , but sometime i see that size decrease. for example partition 1 stateStore size is 20G but after 30s while restoration still is in progress it became 17G! is there any reason for this? (my state-store-changelog topic have compact cleanup policy - i think this is irrelevant but i mention it , might be worth )

**i tried to fix issue 1 by setting REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG to 2 min and decreasing MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG to 100 and MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG to 9 min. but still i'm facing this issue and restoration can not be completed.**

thanks for your help :)

edit: i enable kafka debug log and here is logs befor shuttingdown:

```
23:52:33.422 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Invoking poll on main Consumer
23:52:33.422 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Main Consumer poll completed in 0 ms and fetched 0 records
23:52:33.422 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] State is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED; initializing tasks if necessary
23:52:33.      [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Initialization call done. State is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED
23:52:33.422 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Idempotently invoking restoration logic in state PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED
23:52:33.423 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
23:52:33.423 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
23:52:33.425 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_3] Skipped preparing RESTORING task for commit since there is nothing to commit
23:52:33.425 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_3] Suspended RESTORING
23:52:33.431 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_3] Closing its state manager and all the registered state stores: {Stats=StateStoreMetadata (Stats : -aggregator-Stats-changelog-3 @ 148773145}
23:52:33.432 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): -aggregator-Stats-changelog-4, -aggregator-Stats-changelog-5, -aggregator-Stats-changelog-0, -aggregator-Stats-changelog-2, -aggregator-Stats-changelog-1
23:52:33.435 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.s.i.m.RocksDBMetricsRecorder | [RocksDB Metrics Recorder for Stats] Removing value providers for store Stats of task 0_3
23:52:33.435 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.s.i.m.RocksDBMetricsRecorder | [RocksDB Metrics Recorder for Stats] Removing metrics recorder for store Stats of task 0_3 from metrics recording trigger
23:52:35.193 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=-aggregator] Sending Heartbeat request with generation 111 and member id -aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-consumer-e81c4fa1-8980-4e07-af8f-6de7ddeb2801 to coordinator 172.16.10.110:9092 (id: 2147483637 rack: null)
23:52:35.194 | [39mDEBUG[0;
.
.
.

23:59:06.017 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=-aggregator] Received successful Heartbeat response
23:59:07.122 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StateDirectory | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Released state dir lock for task 0_2
23:59:07.122 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_2] Closing record collector dirty
23:59:07.122 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_2] Closed dirty
23:59:07.122 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Skipped preparing RESTORING task for commit since there is nothing to commit
23:59:07.122 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Suspended RESTORING
23:59:07.124 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Closing its state manager and all the registered state stores: {Stats=StateStoreMetadata (Stats : -aggregator-Stats-changelog-0 @ 214094739}
23:59:07.124 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): -aggregator-Stats-changelog-4, -aggregator-Stats-changelog-1
23:59:07.124 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.s.i.m.RocksDBMetricsRecorder | [RocksDB Metrics Recorder for Stats] Removing value providers for store Stats of task 0_0
23:59:07.124 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.s.i.m.RocksDBMetricsRecorder | [RocksDB Metrics Recorder for Stats] Removing metrics recorder for store Stats of task 0_0 from metrics recording trigger
23:59:07.342 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StateDirectory | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Released state dir lock for task 0_0
23:59:07.342 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Closing record collector dirty
23:59:07.342 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Closed dirty
23:59:07.342 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_4] Skipped preparing RESTORING task for commit since there is nothing to commit
23:59:07.343 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_4] Suspended RESTORING
23:59:07.343 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_4] Closing its state manager and all the registered state stores: {Stats=StateStoreMetadata (Stats : -aggregator-Stats-changelog-4 @ 196360274}
23:59:07.343 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Subscribed to partition(s): -aggregator-Stats-changelog-1
23:59:07.344 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.s.i.m.RocksDBMetricsRecorder | [RocksDB Metrics Recorder for Stats] Removing value providers for store Stats of task 0_4
23:59:07.344 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.s.i.m.RocksDBMetricsRecorder | [RocksDB Metrics Recorder for Stats] Removing metrics recorder for store Stats of task 0_4 from metrics recording trigger
23:59:07.541 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StateDirectory | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Released state dir lock for task 0_4
23:59:07.541 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_4] Closing record collector dirty
23:59:07.541 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_4] Closed dirty
23:59:07.541 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_1] Skipped preparing RESTORING task for commit since there is nothing to commit
23:59:07.541 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_1] Suspended RESTORING
23:59:07.542 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_1] Closing its state manager and all the registered state stores: {Stats=StateStoreMetadata (Stats : -aggregator-Stats-changelog-1 @ 131295699}
23:59:07.542 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
23:59:07.542 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.s.i.m.RocksDBMetricsRecorder | [RocksDB Metrics Recorder for Stats] Removing value providers for store Stats of task 0_1
23:59:07.542 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.s.i.m.RocksDBMetricsRecorder | [RocksDB Metrics Recorder for Stats] Removing metrics recorder for store Stats of task 0_1 from metrics recording trigger
23:59:07.799 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StateDirectory | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Released state dir lock for task 0_1
23:59:07.799 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.RecordCollectorImpl | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_1] Closing record collector dirty
23:59:07.799 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] task [0_1] Closed dirty
23:59:07.803 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer | [Producer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
23:59:07.804 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.c.p.i.Sender | [Producer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-producer] Beginning shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread, sending remaining records.
23:59:07.809 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.c.p.i.Sender | [Producer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-producer] Shutdown of Kafka producer I/O thread has completed.
23:59:07.809 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics scheduler closed
23:59:07.809 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
23:59:07.809 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics reporters closed
23:59:07.810 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser | App info kafka.producer for -aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-producer unregistered
23:59:07.810 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer | [Producer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-producer] Kafka producer has been closed
23:59:07.811 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
23:59:07.811 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=-aggregator] Heartbeat thread has closed
23:59:07.812 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics scheduler closed
23:59:07.812 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
23:59:07.812 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics reporters closed
23:59:07.815 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser | App info kafka.consumer for -aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-consumer unregistered
23:59:07.815 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=-aggregator] Kafka consumer has been closed
23:59:07.815 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics scheduler closed
23:59:07.815 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
23:59:07.815 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.m.Metrics | Metrics reporters closed
23:59:07.819 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser | App info kafka.consumer for -aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer unregistered
23:59:07.819 | [39mDEBUG[0;39m| o.a.k.c.c.KafkaConsumer | [Consumer clientId=-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Kafka consumer has been closed
23:59:07.820 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
23:59:07.820 | [34mINFO [0;39m| o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread | stream-thread [-aggregator-7a670705-853c-4ce9-a223-78ff5fe0a9be-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
```

---